# Has any character or setting introduced in a Marvel TV show gone on to appear in a movie?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, continuity

As may be well known, there is a rift between Marvel Studios and Marvel Television. In general, while officially set in the same universe, the shows will reference the movies, but the movies won't reference the shows.

Is there any instance of a character, setting, or event that was introduced for one of the MCU shows (i.e. SHIELD, Carter, Daredevil, Jessica Jones) which has than gone on to appear in a MCU movie?

Comment: If is really a rift? Or is it the more popular medium not wanting to include in-jokes for the small section of its audience that may have seen episode Y of X show? How often does either the shows or the movies create entirely original characters, settings or plot (as in, not taking from the comics)?

Comment: @TZHX I more of meant "introduced" than "created". I'll try clarifying the question.

Comment: The entire plot of Wandavision is the setting for the new Doctor Strange film

Comment: @Valorum - WandaVision is Marvel Studios. This question was asking about Marvel Television.

Comment: @ibid - Hence not posted as an answer

Answer (score 10):

Here are three candidates that spring to mind. All three of these are concepts that have roots in the comics, but first appeared in the MCU in *Agents of SHIELD*:

- **The Red Room.**  This is the Soviet training facility where Dottie Underwood (*Agent Carter*) and Black Widow were both trained as children.

  It appears in *Agent Carter* s01e05, which aired in February 2015 – we see Dottie as a child in the Red Room, and the Howling Commandos find the abandoned facility.

  Then in *Age of Ultron*, which was released in May, Black Widow has flashbacks (induced by Scarlet Witch) to her time in the Red Room.
- **The Inhumans.** This was a major plotline in the second series of *Agents of SHIELD*, and Marvel have also announced a 2019 movie titled *Inhumans*, which will introduce them to the movie franchise.
- **The Kree.** We see a Kree corpse in *Agents of SHIELD* s01e14 (March 2014), although at the time the exact species isn’t recognised. They get namechecked by Lady Sif in s01e15. (I don’t think we get confirmation that it’s a Kree corpse until series 2.)

  Their movie debut is *Guardians of the Galaxy*, which was released in August 2014.

I can’t think of any MCU-original characters or settings that were carried over to the films, although I recall seeing interviews with Marvel execs who said they weren’t opposed to the idea.

In general, crumbs tend to fall in the other direction.

Comment: It does remain to be seen if the inhumans in the movies will have any connection to the inhumans in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

Comment: [Clark Gregg: "The Inhumans movie I suspect will be its own cinematic version,{...}What's kind of necessary for the show to work is that it is its own thing and it's not dependant upon those crossovers," Gregg suggested. "They're just fun stuff that happens once in a while"](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/agents-of-shield/news/a779043/marvels-inhumans-movie-will-be-its-own-cinematic-version-says-agents-of-shield-star-clark-gregg/)

Comment: Weren't the Kree in the Avengers EMH cartoon?

Comment: @RedCaio Possibly, but I don’t think that’s part of the MCU, is it?

Comment: It's not in the MCU. I was confused because the question sounded like it was talking about stuff that the tv shows *created* brand new and I was pointing out that Kree weren't new. The question is confusing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the Hydra leader **List** count?

He appeared for a few episodes in *Agents of SH.I.E.L.D*, and then got killed by Iron Man in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Comment: Well technically, List **first** appeared in the Cap 2 after credit scene, so he probably doesn't count.

Comment: No, the first appearance has to be on one of the TV shows.